# C# compile .net-core 3.1 portable

Tags: c#, compilation, asp.net-core-3.1, publishing, portable-executable

I´ve written a programm which reads some Printer-Information using `.net-core 3.1` with `Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App.WPF` where `System.Printing.dll` is included. Compiling and running on my machine, everything works fine. But if I publish the programm with Publish-Profile:

```
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
    <Platform>x64</Platform>
    <PublishDir>bin\Release\netcoreapp3.1\publish\</PublishDir>
    <PublishProtocol>FileSystem</PublishProtocol>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <SelfContained>false</SelfContained>
  </PropertyGroup>
```

And move it to the Target-Windows-10 I get this error:

```
    It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App', version '3.1.0' was not found.
  - No frameworks were found.

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.WindowsDesktop.App&framework_version=3.1.0&arch=x64&rid=win10-x64
```

I can´t install .net-core 3.1 on this pc so I it possibile to compile all dll´s into the programm?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/deploying/#publish-self-contained

Comment: You should use self-contained deployment